# Remote Desktop Secutity

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm learning how to remote desktop from my Ubuntu machine to my Debian machine. I'm using Remmina and VNC. One problem I have is that the security is weak. To enable remote desktop on Debian I went to System > Sharing > (double clicked) screen sharing, and configured the settings as shown below. This allowed me to connect to the computer. However, the password text box will only allow you to type an 8 character password. My question is, how do I I increase this character limit? And secondly, why doesn't this work on a user/password model. It seems any non-local user to the Debian machine can login with this password.

[image]

Comment: vnc has it own local password and did not use `PAM`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the 8-character password limit is part of the VNC protocol - some implementations allow the user to *set* a longer password, however the protocol only considers the first 8 characters.

To secure VNC properly, you should tunnel the session over SSH and have the VNC server only listen on the localhost interface, either in its own setup (e.g. adding a `-localhost` option) or by means of a firewall (or both). That way, both the password challenge/response AND the actual VNC traffic will be encrypted.

The Remmina VNC client has support for SSH tunneling built in - with other clients, you may need to set up the tunnel via a separate SSH terminal session.